# React Native Deep Linking

Tags: android, react-native

I have the following block running on compontentDidMount to detect incoming deep links from a web browser.

```
    // Search for deep links
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
        this.navigate(url);
      });
    } else {
      Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
    }
```

My problem is whenever I click a link with the app running in the background, I need to be able to detect the newly clicked link.

i have this function running:

```
handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (nextAppState === 'active') {
     if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
       Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
         this.navigate(url);
       });
     } else {
       Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
     }
    }
  }
```

However this loads whatever link that was clicked to trigger the app to load in the first place.

Can anyone help me identify how to detect a link clicked in the browser with the app running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Add the eventListener whether it's Android or iOS. The event will fire when the app is in the background. Getting the Linking.getInitialURL() is only necessary for Android.